# BFS "Digit Jump" solution working fine on machine, get TLE on online judge

Tags: infinite-loop, breadth-first-search

This code is for problem [DIGJUMP](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DIGJUMP).

It gives me correct output for all inputs i have tried (i have tried a lot of them). But the problem is that it is getting TLE while submitting it on codechef. I checked the editorial and the same solution (concept-wise) gets accepted, so it means algorithmic approach is correct. I must have something wrong in the implementation.

I tried it for a long time, but could not figure out what is wrong.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
    int idx, steps;
};

int main()
{
    char str[100001];
    scanf("%s", str);
    int len = strlen(str);

    vector<int> adj[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        adj[str[i] - '0'].push_back(i);

    int idx, chi, size, steps;
    Node tmpn;
    tmpn.idx = 0;
    tmpn.steps = 0;

    queue<Node> que;
    que.push(tmpn);

    bool * visited = new bool[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    while(!que.empty())
    {
        tmpn = que.front();
        que.pop();
        idx = tmpn.idx;
        steps = tmpn.steps;
        chi = str[idx] - '0';

        if(visited[idx])
            continue;
        visited[idx] = true;

        if(idx == len - 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", tmpn.steps);
            return 0;
        }

        if(visited[idx + 1] == false)
        {
            tmpn.idx = idx + 1;
            tmpn.steps = steps + 1;
            que.push(tmpn);
        }

        if(idx > 0 && visited[idx - 1] == false)
        {
            tmpn.idx = idx - 1;
            tmpn.steps = steps + 1;
            que.push(tmpn);
        }

        size = adj[chi].size();
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if(visited[adj[chi][j]] == false)
            {
                tmpn.idx = adj[chi][j];
                tmpn.steps = steps + 1;
                que.push(tmpn);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution won't finish in acceptable time for the problem. Remember that BFS is O(E). In a string with O(n) digits of some kind there are O(n^2) edges between those digits. For N=10^5 O(N^2) is too much.

This will need some optimizations like if we came to current node from a similar node, we wont skip further to similar nodes.